# How can I simulate click events in jQuery to make a Slide Show advance automaticly

Tags: jquery, click, slider, slideshow

I have **[THIS](http://www.flymedia.ro/design/slider.html) slideshow**. I want it to **auto-advance unless someone clicks the navigation** elements. 
I was thinking about simulating consecutive click events on each link at a certain amount of time (3000 ms, for instance), but my code is ineffective (I'm not so good at JavaScript/jQuery, I admit it). Martin Angelov's [nice tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/01/how-to-make-auto-advancing-slideshows/), unfortunately does not meet my needs. 
Can anyone give a hand please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version adapted from the function in the linked tutorial.  The code could be more condensed, but I tried to make it as clear as possible what's going on.

```
    (function autoAdvance(index){
    //We use index to keep track of which nav link you should be clicking on.

    //Click on the next nav link
    var allNavLinks = $('#slidernav a'); //This selector gets every anchor that is a descendant of your slidernav list
    var currentNavLink = allNavLinks.get(index);
    currentNavLink.click(); //Simulates a click on your nav link

    // Schedule your next autoAdvance
    var clickNextFn = function(){autoAdvance((index+1)%allNavLinks.length)}; //You need to wrap the callback to autoAdvance in a function so that setTimeout can evaluate it later.
    timeOut = setTimeout(clickNextFn,5000); //Will call the clickNextFn in 5 seconds
})(0); //Start the function by auto clicking on index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ButtonID").click()
```

The `.click()` function simulates a click in jQuery. 
Note that this click is not limited to buttons.

Comment: While true, isn't very helpful.